# Mapping a dataframe with a def function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

Error:
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`

Code:
I created a function to classify some of the temporal events(rows) in my dataframe according to values in different columns.

```
def usage(x):
    if x['Dest']==x['Origin']: return 'round'
    elif x['Origin']==x['next_dest']:
        if x['Dest']==x['next_origin']: return 'perfectsym'
        else: return 'nonperfectsym'
    else: 'None'
```

With this, I was hoping to be able to use the map function to classify the entries in a new column as follows:

`All_data['usagetype'] = All_Data.map(usage)`

But this doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

The equivalent of `map` at the dataframe level is `apply`:

```
All_data['usagetype'] = All_Data.apply(usage, axis=1)
```

**Alternative and commentary:**

But for something like this, a fairly straightforward line-by-line conditional, you could get a faster computation with `np.where`:

```
def  usage2(df):
    return np.where(df['Dest'] == df['Origin'], 'round',
                    np.where(df['Origin'] == df['next_dest'],
                             np.where(df['Dest'] == df['next_origin'],
                                      'perfectsym', 'nonperfectsym'),
                             None))

All_data['usagetype'] = usage2(All_Data)
```

Which is around a hundred times faster on 1000 rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 4, size=(1000, 4)),
                  columns=['Dest', 'Origin', 'next_dest', 'next_origin'])

%timeit usage2(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 463 µs per loop

%timeit df.apply(usage, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 46.1 ms per loop
```

I'd also recommend removing the quotes around `None`, as I did in `usage2` above, unless you explicitly want the string "None" and not a `NaN` value.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So, I got this error when I used `apply`: `KeyError: ('Dest', 'occurred at index Dest')`. However, the alternative method works!

Comment: @Helk glad it worked. When using `apply`, did you specify `axis=1` as I did above? That's the error I'd get letting it default to `axis=0`, where it would attempt to iterate across the columns, looking for rows with indices `Dest`, `Origin`, and so on.

Comment: oh, that's right! I had forgotten to specify the axis. :)